# How to check who sent the message inside the IBAction

Tags: ios, swift

I want to use this IBAction func as a general func

```
@IBAction func test(_ sender: Any) {
}
```

How can I know that the sender is an UIButton?

Comment: Well, you can always test `sender is UIButton` or `if let button = sender as? UIButton`. However, using actions as general functions is a bad idea from code readability perspective. Ideally, every button should have its own handler. In some cases it is fine to reuse the same function for different button but it never makes sense to reuse the same handler for completely different actions.

Comment: Solved, thanks @Sulthan

Comment: if let button = sender as? UIButton {
   
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set a different tag  for each button. Then test which tag as the sender to know which button is tapped.

```
@IBAction func test(_ sender: Any) {
    if let tag = (sender as? UIView).tag {
        switch tag {
        :/ add case for each tab value
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    @IBAction func test(_ sender: Any) {
        if let button = sender as? UIButton {
            // Do something with button
        }
        
        // If you don't use the button
        if sender is UIButton {
            // Do something
        }
    }
```